# ANDROID: Layouts do not look the same on different devices

Tags: java, android, size, screen

I recently had a friend with a basic low resolution droid download my app. Everything was looking about the same, but her phone made the text seem larger than mine. This is okay, but then she went to a layout that had a grid view and this happened:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ha6P.jpg

As you see the grid falls off the screen.

Here is what it looks like on my LG G3 phone:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z0m9.jpg

I was confused as in my layout I used "dp" as the size. Here is the layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:background="#ff000000"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:id="@+id/activity_game">

<Button
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="@string/back"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#ffff274a"
    android:id="@+id/back_button"/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/show_unknown_distance_button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ff59e4ff"/>

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="43dp"
    android:rowCount="5"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/zero_zero"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/zero_one"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/zero_two"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/zero_three"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/zero_four"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/one_zero"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/one_one"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/one_two"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/one_three"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/one_four"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/two_zero"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/two_one"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/two_two"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/two_three"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/two_four"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/three_zero"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/three_one"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/three_two"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/three_three"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/three_four"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/four_zero"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/four_one"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/four_two"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/four_three"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/four_four"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="4" />




    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why this might be?

Thanks for all help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can set layout qualifiers for different screens. have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is Simple Solution for this:

1. Set LinearLayout height and widht to match_parent.
2. Inside this LinearLayout, 
   Use **android:weightSum=""**;
3. Set the **layout_weight** for each section of button to same value(ex:1) and    layout_height to 0dp